# Insert Jquery in MySQL through PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, jquery

I am new to jQuery and MySQL inserting. My goal is to insert Phonegap application data in MySQL but unfortunately I'm having a difficult time executing. So I started now in the basic jQuery-AJAX inserting through PHP but still it is not working. Can someone help me? Thank you.

Here's my **testjs.html** file

```
<html>
<head>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#button").click(function(){

                      var name=$("#name").val();
                      var message=$("#message").val();

                      $.ajax({
                          type:"post",
                          url:"process.php",
                          data:"name="+name+"&message="+message,
                          success:function(data){
                             $("#info").html(data);
                          }

                      });

                });
           });
   </script>
 </head>

 <body>
      <form id = "commentform"> 
           name : <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
           </br>
           message : <input type="text" name="message" id="message" />
           </br>
           <input type = "submit" id = "button" value="Send Comment">

           <div id="info" />   <span id="msg"></span>              
      </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and here's my **process.php** file

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("comments");

$name=$_POST["name"];
$message=$_POST["message"];

$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment2 (name,message) values('$name','$message') ");

if($query){
    echo "Your comment has been sent";
}
else{
    echo "Error in sending your comment";
}
?>
```

I dont know where I am wrong because when I run testjs.html in my browser I get no result. Even this message "Your comment has been sent" is not displaying and if I run my process.php file alone, it's working. Of course there is a problem on these parts because

```
$name=$_POST["name"];
$message=$_POST["message"];
```

I manually run it without getting the value from the HTML file. I downloaded my own jquery.js and make it as a source but still not working. All of my files are in one folder under my xampp/htdocs. Thank you.

Comment: try calling the url //localhost/process.php

Comment: You're **very** vulnerable towards SQL injection. [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: it sounds like your ajax is not finding the php file, where in relation to your php file is your js file?  Also, before you even get to your SQL statement, i would try to simply echo something out at the top of the page and console.log() your data param to see if you are getting anything back.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#button").click(function() {

      var name=$("#name").val();
      var message=$("#message").val();

      $.ajax({
          type:"post",
          url:"process.php",
          data:"name="+name+"&message="+message,
          success:function(data){
             $("#info").html(data);
          }

      });
      return false;

});
```

Add `return false` after calling ajax

Comment: Thank you for your help but after trying all your suggestions, i still got no results. no changes in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
        var name=$("#name").val();
        var message=$("#message").val();

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"process.php",
            data:{name: name, message: message},
            success:function(data){
               $("#info").html(data);
            }

        });

        return false;
  });
});
```

It wasn't working because your form was submitting and refreshing the page.

Comment: Still not working. Why is it like the button not functioning? no results or error message at all

Comment: Change <div id="info" /> to <div id="info"></div> and try.

Comment: In Chrome, open up the Developer Tools and look at the network requests as you submit your form. See if you get any errors.

Comment: I got two name path. 1. testjs.html
/C:/xampp/htdocs/webs/main and status is success. other one is jquery.min.js
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1 where is the status is failed. Type = pending, Initiator= testjs.html:5
Parser.

Comment: I got this on my console in developer tools. "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined 
GET file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js  "

Answer (score 0):

Try this?  It's untested and based on my memory so it may or may not work.

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault(); // prevent form submission so we can use ajax
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();
        var sendData = { "name": name, "message": message };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: sendData,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#info").html(data);
            }

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
<input type = "submit" id = "button" value="Send Comment">
```

To

```
<input type = "button" id = "button" value="Send Comment">
```

Comment: Still not working but I got this two error on my console in developer tools. "1. Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined 2. GET file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js " it seems like my code is not accepting java script in my use of "$"

Comment: Try to change also  "$(document).ready(function () {" to "jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {"

Comment: so where am i going to defined that? I mean is that something var data= bla bla; or  var response = bla bla; ? I'm sorry I am new in ajax,mysql connection. After searching in some tutorials I dont see their declaration of response,data,d, or result or anything they putting inside  ' success : function(response) { $("#info").html(response); '

Answer (score 0):

Does your db connect work? try adding something like

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db('comments', $link);
```

My suggestion is that you should use PDO or mysqli

Comment: yes, my db connect is working. actually if i run my process.php alone it works. But if i run my testjs.html, it doesn't work anymore. I tried to to put document.write("Hello World!"); under  $("#button").click(function() to check if the button is working but there's no "Hello World!" output. It means that button is not working. Even if I delete all the command and use this ' $("#button").click(function(){
   document.write("Hello World!");
  }); ' Still doesn't working.

Comment: I tested your code and it works for me if i add this:                  $("#button").click(function(e)  { e.preventDefault();